# Any way to imbed a function or procedure inside Application.OnKey in Excel/VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code in excel using Application.OnKey, which is basically to assign a key to a procedure. For example, Application.OnKey "a", "GO" makes the procedure "GO" run every time "a" is pushed.

I'm looking to make it a bit more customizable using Range("aCell").Value, so it would look like this:

Application.OnKey "Range("aCell").Value", "GO"

with the intent of excel reading the contents of the desired cell and then assigning the key to "GO"...  Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't put Range("aCell").Value in quotes.

Comment: I tried that, it keeps giving me Method 'OnKey' of object '_Application' failed and then a run time error 1004... thanks though!

Comment: Nevermind, I understand!!! Thank you!!!